# Disable X-Powered-By in JBOSS AS 7.1.1 Final

Tags: apache, jboss7.x

I want to remove Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 and X-Powered-By  JSP/2.2 from response header in Jboss AS 7.1.1 final. I tried a lot but could not found any thing.

What i tried is

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <configuration>
                <static-resources listings="true"/>
                <jsp-configuration development="true" x-powered-by="false" display-source-fragment="false"/>
            </configuration>
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

but this is not working, Still same response headers are comming.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To modify Server header you can use the system property:

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.SERVER
```

Eg:

```xml
<system-properties>
     <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.SERVER" value="myserver"/>
</system-properties>
```

About **X-Powered-By** header there is a known issue in 7.1.1 that `jsp-configuration` element is not properly processed by the server and as such none of the settings configured are applied. See [jsp configuration is ignored](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4187)

It was fixed in version 7.1.2, you can download and compile this version, or even better upgrade to WildFly 8.x